# Better Laptime but why do I not own the race-event?

Tags: ps3, need-for-speed-shift

I'm playing Need for Speed Shift on my PS3, which I borrowed from a good friend of mine. On every race I can play there is a red dot in the top left corner and the name and laptime of my friend is displayed. As I read on a tooltip during a loadingscreen this means, that he "owns" (?) this race, because he is/was faster then me. I managed to beat his time on the first three tracks an the dot turns green with my name and laptime next to it. After the third race I'm not able to change the dot and information, even if I beat his time.

So which are the requierements to change these dots to green? It cannot be simply "beat the time", because I got a lot of events where my personal best (you can see this in the raceinformation) is far better then his.

Comment: Are you winning the races?

Comment: Sorry. I dont even have the ps3 anymore :/